# Covariance of linear combination of normal distribution is zero implies independence?

Tags: normal-distribution, independence

Let's say we have i.i.d. normal distributions $Z_1, ..., Z_n$.

For some nonzero constants $a_1, \cdots, a_n$ and $b_1, \cdots, b_n$, let

$$X = a_{1}Z_{1} + \cdots + a_{n}Z_{n}\\
Y = b_{1}Z_{1} + \cdots + b_{n}Z_{n}$$

If $X$, $Y$have covariance zero, are $X$ and $Y$ necessarily independent?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is effectively a duplicate. [This one](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/137518/proof-for-linear-combination-of-multivariate-normal-x) addresses the central issue (that (X,Y) will be bivariate normal), from which the answer to your question follows (if that's not obvious see [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/237003/independence-of-linear-combination-of-multivariate-distribution)), but I think there's another one which even more directly addresses this.question

Comment: Yes, $X$ and $Y$ will have a bivariate normal distribution, therefore zero covariance implies independence.

Answer (score 1):

As gammer pointed out in a comment, $X$ and $Y$ enjoy a bivariate normal distribution and so the assumption that $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated suffices to show that $X$ and $Y$ are indeed *independent* (normal) random variables.  However, arriving at the point that $X$ and $Y$ are bivariate normal requires just a tad more work.

A standard definition of *joint normality* of $n$ random variables $Z_1, Z_2, \ldots, Z_n$ is

> $n$ random variables $Z_1, Z_2, \ldots, Z_n$ are said to be *jointly normal* if for all choices of real numbers $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n$, $X=\sum_{i=1}^n a_iZ_i$ is a normal random variable.

Note that $Z_1, Z_2, \ldots, Z_n$ enjoying the property of being jointly normal  implies that $Z_1, Z_2, \ldots, Z_n$ themselves individually are normal random variables. So, in the OP's problem where $Z_1, Z_2, \ldots, Z_n$ are i.i.d. normal, (and hence jointly normal), $X=\sum_{i=1}^n a_iZ_i$ and $Y=\sum_{i=1}^n b_iZ_i$  certainly are normal random variables. Even more, $X$ and $Y$ are *jointly* normal random variables because every linear combination $\alpha X + \beta Y$ of $X$and $Y$ is a normal random variable. Note that
\begin{align}
W &= \alpha X + \beta Y\\
&= \alpha\sum_{i=1}^n a_iZ_i + \beta\sum_{i=1}^n b_iZ_i\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n (\alpha a_i + \beta b_i)Z_i\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n cZ_i
\end{align}
and so $W,$ being a linear combination of the jointly normal $Z_i$ is normal by definition.  So, $X$ and $Y$ are themselves jointly normal, and since they have zero covariance, they are independent too.

---

> *Jointly* normal random variables that are uncorrelated (a.k.a. have zero covariance) are independent normal random variables.
>
> Normal random variables that are uncorrelated (a.k.a. have zero covariance) are *not necessarily* independent.

A common example of normal uncorrelated $X$ and $Y$ that are *not* independent is  $X$ being a standard normal random variable and $Y = BX$ where $B$ is a discrete random variable (independent of $X$) that takes on values $\pm 1$ with equal probability $\frac 12.$. So, a little extra work is needed because we need to supplement the fact that $X$ and $Y$ are normal random variables (which is immediate from the definition of joint normality of the $Z_i$) with the additional fact that $X$ and $Y$ are also *jointly* normal in order to claim that since $X$ and $Y$ are assumed to be uncorrelated, they are also independent.

Answer (score 0):

This must be a duplicate, but impossible to find. Since $Z_a, Z_2, \dotsc, Z_n$ are iid normal, the vector $Z$ have a multinormal distribution (with a diagonal covariance matrix.) Now, a linear combination of the components of a multivariate normal distribution is itself multivariate normal, as proved at [Proof for linear combination of multivariate normal X?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/137518/proof-for-linear-combination-of-multivariate-normal-x) and elsewhere.

So your vector $(X,Y)$ is bivariate normal, and a bivarite normal with correlation zero have independent components. **So the answer is yes**.